# How do I position a subview within a principal view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I created a class in my project and this class is a subclass of another class; I want place this subview in the principal view, I reduced x and y to make it smaller, but it always appears at the top left, how can I set it in other position?

Comment: I created a view without color and up a tableview then when I call the view I see only tableview where I prefer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be easier to answer if you posted some code. Most likely, you need to modify the `frame` property of your view. `frame` is a rectangle (CGRect) that determines the position and size of your view in the coordinate system of its superview. The `bounds` property is similar but expresses origin and size in the coord system of itself (e.g. origin is 0,0).

For other layout tips, look at the `autoresizingMask` and `contentMode` properties of views. In fact, read up on views in general. The Apple docs are good and lots of stuff here about them.